# running fminsearch in a loop for pixel to pixel optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to run the fminsearch function to optimize the objective function PARA. The objective function PARA is defined for an image with SxL pixels and takes a vector x (which is 4x1) to return a scalar for each pixel. I can use fminsearch for S=1 and L=1 but when S>1 or L>1 the function returns the error:

```
 Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

  Error in fminsearch (line 211)
  fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

   Error in fminsearch_ESM (line 11)
        [X(:,Si,Li),Fval(Si,Li)] = fminsearch(@ESM_PARA,[0;0;0;0]);`
```

A snippet of the code that I'm using to loop the optimization for every pixel is listed below. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

```
 S=100;
 L=100;

 X = zeros(4,S,L);
 Fval = zeros(S,L);


 for Si=1:S
    for Li=1:L
       [X(:,Si,Li),Fval(Si,Li)] = fminsearch(@PARA,[0;0;0;0]);
    end
 end
```

The objective function PARA is listed below.

```
function f = PARA(x)
     S=100;
     L=100;
     size(A11) = (3,3,S,L);
     size(A22) = (3,3,S,L);
     size(A12) = (3,3,S,L);
     W=zeros(3,S,L);
     W(1,:,:) = cos(x(1));
     W(2,:,:) = sin(x(1))*cos(x(2))*exp(j*x(3));
     W(3,:,:) = sin(x(1))*sin(x(2))*exp(j*x(4));
     Xdd = zeros(S,L);
     Dxi = zeros(S,L);
     Dxj = zeros(S,L);

      for Si=1:S
             for Li=1:L
               Xdd(Si,Li)=conj(W(:,Si,Li).')*A12(:,:,Si,Li)*W(:,Si,Li);
               Dxi(Si,Li) = conj(W(:,Si,Li).')*A11(:,:,Si,Li)*W(:,Si,Li);
               Dxj(Si,Li) =  conj(W(:,Si,Li).')*A22(:,:,Si,Li)*W(:,Si,Li);
           end
     end
     Axf = sqrt(Dxi.*Dxj);
     f = abs(Xdd./Axf);
 end
```

Comment: You say `PARA` "takes a vector x (which is 4x1) to return a scalar for each pixel". So it returns a vector for anything more than 1x1? In that case Fval(Si,Li) is a scalar and you are assigning the solution, a vector.... Either way, I suggest you solve fminsearch for the dimensions of interest outside of the loop and see what the output looks like to make sure it matches your expectations.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! The function PARA is defined for SxL pixels (S rows and L columns). So this function returns a scalar value per pixel as long as you supply a vector X (4x1) for every pixel. The problem comes when I try to loop fminsearch for pixels other than S=1 and L=1. I think I'm not using the right argument for fminsearch in the for loop...

Comment: can you show us what is happening in your function `PARA`? fminsearch expects a scalar output, and if it is failing on assignment as indicated in your error message above, then that points to your function returning a vector.

Comment: @pragmatist1Please find the function PARA appended to the question.

Comment: Please note that the multidimensional matrices A11, A22 and A12 are imported from a file and the sizes of the matrices is included in the code just to give information.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it is as I said. The function `fminsearch` minimizes a *scalar* function. For any S,L > 1, you are returning a vector (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html). What you need to do is define some sort of objective function that is a scalar. Perhaps return `norm(f, p)` where p is your norm of choice (2 is the default and a very reasonable norm).